# cpprestsdk SSL post not working on Windows7 but works on windows 10

Tags: windows, rest, ssl, visual-c++, casablanca

I have a C++ Windows application, developed using Visual studio 2017 on windows 10 system. This application uses cpprestsdk to post request to REST Server. My application works perfectly fine on windows 10 machine with properly posting request over ssl to rest server. I did not create any local certificate to make my application work on windows 10.

However same application when ported on windows 7 (64 bit), is not able to POST request with SSL protocol to rest server.

Same request works without SSL, (http://HOST/API works)
but (https://host/api fails)
by giving following error.

winhttpsendrequest 12029 a connection with the server could not be established.

From same windows 7, PostMan can successfully post https request.
No clue of what could be wrong with the implementation.

Can any one share what could be the reason of failing the POST request on windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late with the answer but I hope that it might help others who face the same problem ...

I think that your server insists on using tls version higher than 1.0 which is a default on Windows 7. Unfortunately cpprestsdk cannot be configured to use a specific tls version. On Windows cpprestsdk uses WinHTTP which exposes two handles but only one of them can be used to configure tls (I do not remember handle names at the moment). Unfortunately the native handle that cpprestsdk has access to cannot be used to configure tls.

The only workaround is to configure Windows 7 (and indirectly WinHTTP) to use a specific tls version as default. Instructions on how to do that can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi.